# How can you tell which pipe can be entered?

Tags: super-mario-bros

Just curious. Is there a pattern to figure out which pipes lead to another location? I remember trying every one of them.

Comment: There's no indicator one way or the other.  They never change when replaying a level, though, so once you've found them, you know where they are.

Answer (score 6):

In the original Super Mario Bros for SNES (and the majority of Mario games period) there's simply no way to know which pipes "work" without actually pressing down while standing on them. There is no visual, audio or other cue to indicate whether a pipe is enterable or not.

There are certain hints, like if there's only one pipe in a level it's often a working pipe, but generally you just have to try them all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell at a glance which pipes can be entered and which can't. You just have to try them, and remember. [Or cheat.](http://www.themushroomkingdom.net/smb_breakdown.shtml#levels)

Answer (score -1):

You cant tell unless you try but some you can't go in because they have a plant in them. Just a tip try to be careful around them because they can pop up at any moment between 3-7 seconds